# Global attribute localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working with a legacy database schema which uses camelCase for its attributes, which Rails doesn't translate too well into human readable form. For one model I can define eg.

```
en:
  active_record:
    attributes:
      user:
        createDate: "Create date"
```

But that works only for the User model. Is there a way to define "global attribute translations"? Something like

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      global: 
        createDate: "Create date"
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails will lookup translations for attributes in the following places (if your attribute name is not namespaced):

- activerecord.attributes.{model_name}.{attribute_name}
- attributes.{attribute_name}

(take a look at the ruby docs for [human_attribute_name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Translation.html#method-i-human_attribute_name))

so to achieve what you're looking for above you should use the following:

```
en:
  attributes:
    createDate: "Create date"
```

you can still override these 'default' attribute names by adding translations like your first example e.g.

```
en:
  active_record:
    attributes:
      user:
        createDate: "User creation date"
```

will result in:

```
User.human_attribute_name(:createDate) => "User creation date"
Topic.human_attribute_name(:createDate) => "Create date"
SomeOtherModelClass.human_attribute_name(:createDate) => "Create date"
```